# Reflowing Highslide Popup On TinyMCE Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am trying to reflow a highslide popup after TinyMCE loads as it takes up more space.  I have tried using init_instance_callback and oninit parameters in TinyMCE, however it still triggers before the full HTML is rendered of the TinyMCE area, so it doesn't reflow the page.  A workaround I have is to set the timeout to 1 second after initialization, however I would think there would be a better method?

Here is the code without the setTimeout workaround:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   oninit : "initTinyMCEComplete"
});

function initTinyMCEComplete() {
   var expander = top.hs.getExpander();
   if (expander) {
      expander.reflow();
   }
}
```

In case you are wondering, I have checked to make sure it is getting to the expander.reflow().

Thanks.